# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 4 unexpected 'S'. Getting this error while calling the procedure

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Proc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Swapna_test_proc20)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var err="
var procResult2 = DATA SUCCESSFULLY LOADED":
try
{
var table_load = 'Select "WHOLESALE_ID" from
CPH DB DEV ENRICH BV ANALYTICS_CH GALEXIS GUTSCHRIFT OUTBOUND BONUSANDDISCOUNT_INVOI
var table load stmt = snowflake.createStatement ((sqlText: table load)).
var exe_table_load_stmt = table_load_stmt.execute();
var columnValue load = exe_table_load_stmt.getColumnValue("WHOLESALE_ID');
var substring load qry= select substring(1,1,3) as extracted string from '+columnValue_load
```

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 4 unexpected 'S'.

Getting this error while calling the procedure

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [edit] your question, please.

Comment: Hi - your SELECT statement isn’t valid. What are all the words after “from” meant to be doing?

Comment: seems to be incomplete code